# How to create Tests \ Tested By relationships quickly?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

i have a lot of "Test Cases" and "Features" ( somthing around 100 - 200  test cases and feauters )

how i can quickly to create "Tests \ Tested By" relationships between them ?

( i know "Add Link" function , but so i will have to create that relation one by one )

an addition :

just now "Test Cases" is not created , i will be to create them using Excel . so maybe i can to do it in same time ? ( create "test cases" using excel and to create "tests \  tested by" relations )

thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both test cases and features essentially are work items in TFS. You could use [Bulk modify work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=vsts):

- How to multi-select work items from a list and open the context menu
- Edit one or more fields of several work items
- Assign work from a backlog to a sprint using drag-and-drop
- Add or remove tags from several work items

Note:

> To add work items in bulk or update multiple fields with different
>   values, use **[Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts)**. You can't perform a bulk add of work items
>   through the web portal.

You have to do this in Excel, test case work item can only have a parent, but we could link the task as the other type, such as Related, Test Case.

We could type the work item IDs or use query to get work items. And do the link in excel. Finally import all work items back to TFS.